# In the figure angle AB is inscribed in thesemicircle. What is the value of angleD C A (C is the centre of the circle)?

Tags: geometry, triangles

In the figure angle, AB is inscribed in the semicircle. What is the value of angleD
C
A (C is the centre of the circle)?

(A)61o
(B)129o
(C)58o
(D)122o
(E)121o

[image]

Comment: What is angle $\angle ADB$? What is the relationship between angle $\angle ABD$ and the circular arc running from $A$ to $D$?  What is the the relationship between angle $\angle ACD$ and the circular arc running from $A$ to $D$?  Either you have been trained to answer all $3$ of these questions or you haven't.  If you haven't been trained to answer all $3$ of these questions, then you have not received the proper training to attack the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\angle BDA$ in the semicircle is a right angle,  you know$$\angle ABD=180^o-90^o-29^o=61^o$$And since an angle at the center of a circle is double an angle at the circumference standing on the same arc, then$$\angle DCA=2\angle ABD=122^o$$